# How I can get the critical points of this system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've got this dynamic system:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(1-x)-\frac{\alpha xy}{x+\gamma}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \beta y\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
Where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ $>0$ .

How can I get the critical points?

I have found four: $\{{0,0}\},\{{1,0}\}$ and
$$
\Bigg\{ \frac{1-\alpha-\gamma-\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2},\frac{1-\alpha-\gamma-\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2}\Bigg\}
$$
$$
\Bigg\{ \frac{1-\alpha-\gamma+\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2},\frac{1-\alpha-\gamma+\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2}\Bigg\}
$$

I also want to plot the equations when $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$.

I though the critical points will be the points where the functions meet. But they aren't, furthermore $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ is (or at least that is what i got) a straight line, thus they can only meet twice ($\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ seems to be a parabola).

Can someone confirm me if the critical points are correct and guide me to plot the functions? I usually use Maple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

Prior to answering your question, I will provide my answer with a context by stating several relevant definitions. Suppose you are given a system of (autonomous) differential equations $Dy=f(y)$, where $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $U$ is an open set such that $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (with appropriate smoothness conditions on $f$). An equilibrium point (or a critical point) is (sometimes) defined as a function $y$, such that there exists $c \in U$, such that $y(t)=c$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(c)=0$ (some general references could be ["Solving Differential Equations on Manifolds" by Ernst Hairer](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly-sde-mani.pdf) and "Nonlinear Control Systems" by Horacio J. Marquez). For simplicity, we identify the critical point with the constant $c\in U$.

---

**Critical points**

In your case, the dimension of the problem $n$ is 2. Also, $f=(f_1, f_2)^T$ is given by

- (1) $f_1(x,y) = x(1-x)-\frac{\alpha x y}{x + \gamma}$
- (2) $f_2(x,y) = \beta y (1 - \frac{y}{x})$

for all $(x,y)\in U$.

However, the possible domain $U$ of the definition of $f$ is implicitly restricted by the value of the parameter $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $(-\gamma, y)\notin U$ for all admissible $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $(0,y)\notin U$ for all admissible $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, let us define $U$ as $U = \mathbb{R^2} - \{(x, y). x = -\gamma \lor x = 0\}$.

Suppose $(x,y)\in U$ is a critical point. Then, from (2), $\beta y (1 - \frac{y}{x})=0$. Thus, given that $\beta > 0$, $y = 0$ or $y = x$. Coniser these two cases explicitly:

- Case I: $y = 0$. Then, from (2), for $(x,y)$ to be a critical point we also need $x (1 - x) = 0$. Thus, $x = 0$ or $x = 1$. However, as previously established, $(0,y)\notin U$. Thus $(x_1, y_1) = (1, 0)$ is the only possible critical point in this case. It is, indeed, a critical point, which can be verified by substitution into $f(x,y)=0$.
- Case II: $y = x$. Then, from (1), $x^2 + x(\alpha+\gamma-1) - \gamma = 0$. Solving for $x$ and substituting yields the two possible critical points from your answer:
  $
  (x_2,y_2) = \left( \frac{1-\alpha-\gamma-\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2},\frac{1-\alpha-\gamma-\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2}\right)
  $ and 
  $
  (x_3,y_3) =\left( \frac{1-\alpha-\gamma+\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2},\frac{1-\alpha-\gamma+\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2}\right)
  $. However, for these points to be, indeed, critical points, it is also necessary to ensure that $(\alpha + \gamma - 1)^2 + 4 \gamma \geq 0$. Luckily, given that $\gamma>0$, this condition is always satisfied. Furthermore, we need $x \neq -\gamma$ and $x \neq 0$. These conditions should also be satisfied, given that $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are greater than $0$, based on my rough estimates (please double check this!). By substitution, indeed, $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ are critical points.

In summary, given the restrictions on the set of parameters, the system should always have exactly three critical points:

- $(1, 0)$
- $\left( \frac{1-\alpha-\gamma-\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2},\frac{1-\alpha-\gamma-\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2}\right)$
- $\left( \frac{1-\alpha-\gamma+\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2},\frac{1-\alpha-\gamma+\sqrt{(\alpha+\gamma-1)^2+4\gamma}}{2}\right)$

This is consistent with your answer, with the exception that $(0,0)$ is not a critical point based on the definitional framework that is commonly used for such problems.

---

**Plots**

From (1), taking into account the restrictions on the values of the parameters, $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ if and only if either $x=0$ or $y = -\frac{1}{\alpha}x^2+x\frac{1-\gamma}{\alpha}+\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}$ and $x\neq-\gamma$. If $y = -\frac{1}{\alpha}x^2+x\frac{1-\gamma}{\alpha}+\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}$ and $x=-\gamma$, then $y = 0$. Thus, technically, the plot of $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ should consist of two lines: one is a vertical line at $x=0$ and another one is a parabola given above with the point $(-\gamma,0)$ missing. However, it is likely that you are only interested in the points $(x,y)$ such that they belong to the domain of the state function. In this case, you should omit the vertical line at $x=0$ and only leave the 'punctured' parabola.

From (2), taking into account the restrictions on the values of the parameters, $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ if and only if either $y=0$ and $x \neq 0$ or $y = x$ and $x \neq 0$. Thus, the plot should consist of two lines: the first one is a horizontal line $y = 0$ and the other one $y = x$ with the point $(0,0)$ being omitted. This explains why there are three points of intersection.

---

Comment: Thank you very much. One of the things that gave me headche me was that (0,0) point, now I undestand.